# UITableView Accessory View not being displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, imageview

Why is the following not displaying the  proper UITableView accessory view?  It is simply displaying the UIAcessoryTypeCheckmark that was selected in the nib file.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Selection";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = tvCell;
        self.tvCell = nil;
    }   
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 70.0f;

    //Background
    BOOL useDarkBackground = NO; //odd
    if(indexPath.row %2 == 0) useDarkBackground = YES; //even
    NSString *backgroundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:useDarkBackground ? @"DarkBackground" : @"LightBackground" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImagePath] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:1.0];
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
    cell.backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    cell.backgroundView.frame = cell.bounds;

    //Checkmark
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSString *checkmarkImagePath;
    checkmarkImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[selectedObjects containsObject:managedObject] ? @"checkSelected" : @"checkUnselected" ofType:@"png"];
    if([selectedObjects count] == 0) {
        checkmarkImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"checkUnselected" ofType:@"png"];
    }   
            UIImage *checkmarkImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:checkmarkImagePath] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:1.0];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:checkmarkImage] autorelease];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, imageView.frame.size.width/1.2, imageView.frame.size.height/1.2);

    return cell;

}
```

For some reason, the following **does** work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSManagedObject *objectToChange = [[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //The object

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *checkmarkImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[selectedObjects containsObject:objectToChange] ? @"checkSelected" : @"checkUnselected" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *checkmarkImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:checkmarkImagePath] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:1.0];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:checkmarkImage] autorelease];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, imageView.frame.size.width/1.2, imageView.frame.size.height/1.2);

cell.accessoryView = imageView;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're adding the `UIImageView` to the accessory view of the cell in the first code block.

You're also leaking all over the place. Make sure you adhere to the [memory management guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) set forth by Apple.

Comment: I understand that I have a lot of memory leaks.  I know what to fix, and will fix it once I actually have something that works

Comment: @joshim5 - you didn't ask, but I'm going to comment anyway - it will serve you well to get in the habit early of writing your code without memory leaks in the first place.  Pretty soon you won't have to think about it, and you won't have to fix leaks that slip into production code.  My 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you are not assigning the accessoryView to the cell, as you are in the didSelect method.